# How to check if a proposition is a necessary and/or sufficient condition for another proposition - Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> P: (x⇒y)⇒z
>
> Use truth tables to determine whether the following proposition is a
>   necessary and/or sufficient condition for p to be true:
>
> x⇒(y⇒z)

I did the truth table and I know that antecedent is sufficient and consequent is necessary, but I don't know where to go from there. Should I take P as antecedent and the other proposition as consequent?

```
x    y    z    x⇒y   (x⇒y)⇒z    y⇒z    x⇒(y⇒z)
0    0    0     1         0        1         1
0    0    1     1         1        1         1
0    1    0     1         0        0         1
0    1    1     1         1        1         1
1    0    0     0         1        1         1
1    0    1     0         1        1         1
1    1    0     1         0        0         0
1    1    1     1         1        1         1
```

Comment: Isn't it 1⟹0, so 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that *B is a necessary condition for A* to mean: $A \rightarrow B$.

And we say also that *A is a sufficient condition for B* to mean: $A \rightarrow B$.

Let $P := (x \to y) \to z$ and $Q := x \to (y \to z)$ and we have to check if $Q$ is a necessary/sufficient condition for $P$.

Thus *Q is a sufficient condition for P* iff $Q \to P$ is true and *Q is a necessary condition for P* iff $P \to Q$ is true.